# Can I reinstall Windows 10 after upgrading from OEM Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-10, partition-recovery

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 laptop. It came with Windows 7 preinstalled, and I upgraded it to Windows 10. A little while after I was wanting to use Ubuntu, so I attempted to install it. I figured out that there were already 4 primary partitions on the hard drive. There was the the two ntfs partitions Windows uses, a third ntfs partition called recovery, and a fat32 partition called hp_tools. I deleted the recovery and fat32 partition. When I attempted to boot Windows 10 after the partitions were deleted, it failed to boot. It stopped a little while into the part with the spinning circle. The error code read: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DRIVE. It automatically restarted, and came up with the recovery and repair menu. I tried clicking reset, but it said the drive was locked. None of the other options worked either. I foolishly didn't back up the computer before messing with the partitions, so the only thing I could think of to do was reinstall Windows 10. I used my desktop to create a bootable Windows 10 installation flash drive. I am not sure if I should format the hard drive and attempt to do that, or what. The only activation key I have is the old Windows 7 one on the sticker on the bottom. Any ideas of what I should do?

Comment: Make a back up now so at least if you make things worse you can get back to where you are now.

Comment: Reinstall W10 clean, it should activate since it already did the first time.

Comment: @Moab Should I format the hard drive first?

Comment: I've never clean installed Windows 10 so I'm not sure whether it will automatically format the hard drive first.

Comment: It should but it may not know what to do with the Ubuntu partitions, I suggest you [wipe the drive with dban first](http://www.dban.org/download), you can run the program for 15 minutes to wipe all partitions, then cancel the wipe, no need to wipe the entire drive as it takes a long time.

Comment: @Moab I suppose I will do that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Wipe the hard drive and then reinstall windows 10. I am not sure if Windows 10 will activate. Though...you could always reinstall windows 7 and then do the upgrade again, and perform backups.

Comment: Windows 7 was preinstalled, so I don't have an installation disc. And Microsoft's website won't allow me to download an iso for windows 7 with the oem product key I have.

Comment: If you have the disk and PK for Win10...just format the HD and install Win 10.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have a windows 10 product key. It automatically activates when you upgrade from 7.

Comment: Modern machines do not come with recovery disks *sigh*. You mentioned that you have a bootable win 10 on a USB drive. Why not boot from that USB drive? How did you reinstall Windows 10?

Comment: I have a bootable usb drive that contains Windows 10 installation files. I have never reinstalled Windows 10, either, but I may have to because of this problem. I just don't know if it would automatically activate, like the Moab guy up there said, or not.

Comment: If W10 was ever activated on that hardware, it will activate doing a clean install , when it asks for a product key just skip it, once the desktop loads it will activate using the previous activation on that hardware profile.

Comment: It might since the windows 7 is imaged/specific to your machine and hard drive S/N (since it was originally installed). You should not have any issues.